# auto_increment next value set to NULL in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am getting the error

```
Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '0' for key 1
```

when inserting a new value to a table where the primary key is set to auto_increment.  This column is set to `int(11)` data type and when you select the max value of the column it is 16000. (Note: I can manually add a new row in with a random high number fine, the issue is purely with auto_increment).

If I do this:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM database LIKE 'tablename'
```

The value of auto_increment is set to `NULL`.

Strangely enough I tried to replicate the table, with the plan to just copy all the existing data over and when I recreated the same table with a new name and there is no data in the table the auto_increment next value is also set to null.

This particular table has a lot of columns so I wonder if maybe I have hit on another limit of some sort?

Comment: Please, show full table definition (i.e. `show create table`)

Comment: agree. table info and insert SQL will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue.  For some reason the column was no longer set to auto-increment.  It had worked fine for the previous 13,000 records so I am not sure why the flag had suddenly been removed.